# What's the difference between e.preventDefault(); and return false?

Tags: jquery

```
$("a.avatar").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#thumbnails").fadeIn();
    });
```

and

```
$("a.avatar").click(function(e){
      $("#thumbnails").fadeIn();
          return false;
    });
```

Both can achieve the same goal for me.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Returning `false` from jQuery event handlers is [equivalent](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.3.2/src/event.js#L270) to calling both, [`e.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault) and [`e.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Event.stopPropagation).

So the difference is that `preventDefault` will only prevent the default event action to occur, i.e. a page redirect on a link click, a form submission, etc. and `return false` will also stop the [event flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow).

Comment: can you give an example where stopping event flow is not desirable?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/ check a demo.