# How to stop event propagating?

Tags: jquery, events

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('<h2>Click</h2>').prependTo($('#container')).live('click',function() {
        return false;
    });
    $('#container').click(function() {
        alert(1);
    });
});
</script>


<div id="container">

</div>
```

I don't want the `click` event to propagate to the `#container`,and that's why there is `return false`,but obviously it's not working

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with using the `live` selector and event delegation. You don't even need that `live` handler. Change your `#container` click like this:

```
$('<h2>Click</h2>').prependTo($('#container'));
$("#container").click(function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName != "H2"){
       alert(1);
    }
});
```

Or if it looks nicer to use all jQuery:

```
$("#container").click(function(e){
    if($(e.target).is('h2') == false){
       alert(1);
    }
});
```

Both of those examples test where the original click happened, and won't execute if a H2 was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `live` for what you're doing - use `bind` (or `click` directly) instead:

```
$('<h2>Click</h2>').prependTo($('#container')).click (function() {
    return false;
});
```

If you really meant a live-binding to `h2`s, you should call:

```
$('h2').live ('click', function () { ... });
```

Comment: Correct - `live` expects a jQuery selector, not a HTML fragment (as you've given above)

Answer (score 0):

Use a parameter to your event handler. That parameter will be bound to the event object:

```
$('<h2>Click</h2>').prependTo($('#container')).live('click',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: No,I think you should see this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017755/whats-the-difference-between-e-preventdefault-and-return-false/2017761#2017761

Comment: Right, I forgot, when a `live` event is handled, it has already bubbled up to the document (I think), so stopping propagation has no effect. Thanks for the downvote, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

live cannot be used to a jquery object like this.

Quoting from [Events/live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live):

> Live events currently only work when
>   used against a selector. For example,
>   this would work: $("li a").live(...)
>   but this would not: $("a",
>   someElement).live(...) and neither
>   would this: $("a").parent().live(...).

Comment: I tried this,but still failed:

$h2 = $('<h2>Click</h2>').prependTo($('#container'));
 $($h2,$('#container')).live('click',function() {
  return false;
 });

Comment: Incidentally, Jquery 1.4 now supports context for `live` - so `$('a', someElement).live ()` would actually work