# Using jQuery's animate(), if the clicked on element is "<a href="#" ...> </a>", the function should still return false?

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-events, dhtml, dynamic-html

I was reading jQuery's page for animate()

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Its examples don't mention about if using

```
<a href="#" id="clickme">click me</a>
...

$('#clickme').click(function() {
    $('#someDiv').animate({left: "+=60"});
})
```

we actually still have to return false like in the old days?

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    $('#someDiv').animate({left: "+=60"});
    return false;
})
```

(but then, those examples didn't use a `<a>` for the "click me"... but used something else.

Otherwise the page will jump back to the beginning of the page? Does jQuery have a more elegant or magical way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/):

```
$('...').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Code.
});
```

From the [jQuery Website](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/):

> event.preventDefault()
>   Description:
>   If this method is called, the default
>   action of the event will not be
>   triggered.

Comment: return false works too... is the eventPreventDefault() better?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017755/whats-the-difference-between-e-preventdefault-and-return-false