# How to convert selectors and event capturing from jQuery to plain JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please help with converting this code to plain JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("textarea").bind("keydown", function(event) {
        var textarea = $(this).get(0);          
        //further will need only textarea and event vars
    }
});
```

I don't care about cross browser compatibility as long as it works in current FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your selector is quite simple, you are looking for all the `textarea` elements, then you can use the [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) method.

To simulate `$(document).ready`, we can bind the `DOMContentLoaded` event e.g.:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var allTextAreas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
  // event handler
  var handler = function (event) {
    var textarea = this;
    //...
  };

  // iterate over the textareas and bind the event
  for(var i = 0, len = allTextAreas.length; i < len; i++) {
    allTextAreas[i].addEventListener('keydown', handler, false);
  } 
}, false);
```

For CSS selectors, you can use the [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll) method, available on both browsers you are targeting.

See also:

- [Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/)
- [Thoughts on querySelectorAll](http://ejohn.org/blog/thoughts-on-queryselectorall/)

Comment: i would also add `window.onDomReady(onReady)` for `$(document).ready`

Comment: This works, thanks. The only problem is I can't seem to find a way to stop event propagation. I used to just return false from event handler and it would stop all further event processing. Any idea how to make it work in plain js? Thanks again.

Comment: @serg555: Yes, the `addEventListener` method doesn't really expect any return value from the handler, you can use the [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation) method, to stop the normal event flow. Note that in jQuery, returning `false` from an event handler, stops the event propagation and prevents the default action, [more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017755/).

Answer (score 0):

Why convert it to "plain JS"? jQuery essentially is plain JS.  It's just a language built around Javascript.  What is it that's not working for you with jQuery

Comment: Probably to remove the need to load the jQuery library.