# jquery onclick set paragraph/textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have unordered list of links and i am trying to get the clicked link text.
So when i click on some link i would like to display in paragraph or textbox at the bottom of my list text that is cliked.
So if I have something like this:

1. item1
2. item2
3. item3

If i click on item2 i would like to get it like: "You just clicked:item2 "

And i manage that with this:

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        alert('Text is: ' + $(this).text());
    });
});
```

But that is displaying an alert message. then i do this:

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        var name = $(this).text();
        $("p#selector").text(name); 
        $("input#textbox").val(name);
    });
});
```

And it works it send text value of a link to paragraph but it disappear really fast, it show it about second and it's gone, is there any way to prevent this? To stop it from disappearing?

Comment: try with `return false;`..i m not sure

Comment: @user748393: make sure you amend your selectors too - see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $(this).text();
        $("#selector").text(name); 
        $("#textbox").val(name);
    });
});
```

`e.preventDefault()` will prevent the link from doing whatever it is doing by default (which sounds like it could be refreshing the page...).

[**Here's a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/Jxgwa/).

I've also amended your selectors - `p#selector` is inefficient, you should simply use `#selector` when selecting by ID, as documented in the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

> For id selectors, jQuery uses the
>   JavaScript function
>   document.getElementById(), which is
>   extremely efficient. When another
>   selector is attached to the id
>   selector, such as h2#pageTitle, jQuery
>   performs an additional check before
>   identifying the element as a match.

**EDIT:** As it's become apparent that the click handler isn't what you need here, try this solution:

Parse the URL to get the current page using a [jQuery URL Parser](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/url_parser), and then find the link that corresponds to the URL and get the text:

```
var url = "one.htm";
var linktext = $("a[href='" + url + "']").text();
$('#output').text(linktext);
```

[**Working demo of that bit**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/jhbYL/) (just do the URL parsing instead of setting the URL manually).

Comment: yea that is allright but it prevents my link to work.
is there any way to fix that?
I mean i need that link to work i have that list on 5-6 pages and that links are important to me.

Comment: @user748393: Surely you don't want your link to work as a link, isn't that the point?

Comment: @GoranB: 'work' in the sense that it loads a new page? Surely if that happens, you won't see the results of your click handler?

Comment: @Rob yea it should load a new page, i am not so good with jquery i am working on asp.net mvc3 project so i thought it would be cool to use jquery feature, but it seems that i will have to make some workaround

Comment: @GoranB: Like @Rob Cowie says, if you navigate to a different page then the page containing the paragraph won't be there anymore... Maybe update your question with some HTML and a wider description.

Comment: @GoranB: Your use of jquery is fine, and jquery is doing what you are asking it to. The problem - if there is one - is that you are using jquery to update a page _and_ expecting the link to load a _new_ page. If you do that, then the changes you just made (i.e. adding text to a paragraph) will disappear almost immediately.

Comment: @GoranB: @Rob Cowie: I think this could be handled by parsing the URL to get the active page on first load, finding the corresponding link and then displaying the text in the `p` tag.  That way it would show the 'clicked' link (ie: the current page).

Comment: do you have any example of that? 
it would be cool to take the last 3 digits from url becouse in my case it's id andstore it in variable to use on that page

Comment: I think i have found myself another solution my url looks like: http://localhost:7264/Asortiman/Browse?kategorije=327
so is it possible to catch last 3 digits in this case 327 that would save me. i wolud take that number and use it as param to another function

Comment: @Goran B: Use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter).

Answer (score 1):

Try preventing the click event from propagating after you handle it by returning false from the function.

```
jQuery(function() {
    $('a').click(function () {
        var name = $(this).text();
        $("p#selector").text(name); 
        $("input#textbox").val(name);
        return false;
    });
});
```

**EDIT 1:** Which is functionally identical to the answer provided by @Town, who beat me to it

**EDIT 2:** `return false` is not *quite* identical to `.preventDefault()` (which prevents the default event from occurring, but does not prevent other registered handlers from firing) or indeed `.stopPropagation()` (which stops event 'bubbling' and prevents handlers further up the DOM from firing). Returning false causes both *but* as @Town says, if the handler errors before returning, the default event will occur.

Basically... do what he said.

Comment: @Rob Cowie: `e.preventDefault()` will always be called, whereas `return false` will not be reached in the event of an error in the function. `return false` also [prevents all propagation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017755/whats-the-difference-between-e-preventdefault-and-return-false) (which may or may not be desired). So not quite functionally identical ;)

Comment: @Rob Cowie: Haha! And you win the points! Not my day, obviously :p

Comment: @Town: Sheesh... I even mentioned your answer in my edit. Perhaps I should have deleted my post. Sorry 'bout that old boy.

Comment: @Rob Cowie: No problem! Your answer is different so deleting it would have devalued this question. Just bask in the glory mate :)

Comment: @Town: There we go... now I got nothin! Entertaining stuff... beats working.

Comment: @Rob Cowie: I literally have no idea what's going on anymore!