# jQuery replaceWith replace div causes reload

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery replaceWith to replace a visible `<div>` with another. However for some reason when I click the link to initiate the replaceWith, the page reloads and causes the original `<div>` to appear again. Here's my jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $("a#startSlide").click(function () {
        $('div#leftText').replaceWith('div#slide');
    });
});
```

Why is this reloading after the div is replaced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cancel the event, since the default event for an anchor click is to change the window location:

```
$(function(){
    $("a#startSlide").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('div#leftText').replaceWith('div#slide');
    });
});
```

Comment: Won't returning false do the same thing?

Comment: I prefer not to return false. The intention of the code does not obviously imply the behavior of the code, whereas `event.preventDefault()` does exactly what it says and novice devs don't have to guess what it is trying to do.

Comment: @AlienWebguy: `return false;` would be preferable if you have `$('a').click(function() { /* do ajax loading */ })` elsewhere, otherwise your second handler will still execute.

Comment: `return false` won't prevent your example from firing. Its two binds.

Comment: @AlienWebguy: I have a similar problem as tvalent2 except if I use preventDefault it wont do anything at all.
My code is the following:
var html = <div id="container2" class="listContainer"></div>
$('#container').replaceWith(html); inside a script tag
for <div id="container" class="listContainer"></div>

Answer (score 0):

You need to either return false or preventDefault().

```
$(function(){
    $("a#startSlide").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('div#leftText').replaceWith('div#slide');
    });
});
```

OR

```
$(function(){
    $("a#startSlide").click(function (e) {
        $('div#leftText').replaceWith('div#slide');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Note these are _not the same_

Comment: @Eric: True: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017755/whats-the-difference-between-e-preventdefault-and-return-false

Answer (score 0):

Your `<a>` tag presumably has a `href="#"`. This reloads the page when clicked.

When you bind your event handler, you need to cancel your default behaviour:

```
$(function() {
    $('a#startSlide').click(function() {
        $('div#leftText').replaceWith('div#slide');

        return false;
        //equivalent to:
        //  e.preventDefault();
        //  e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Alternatively, you could change your `<a>` tag to be `href="javascript:void()"`.