# Prevent back button in browser?

Tags: html, forms, http, web, browser

I did 30+mins research and I can't figure out what the problem is. I'd like to prevent a user from hitting back in the browser and looking at the page again. How do I prevent it? I did tons of research and looking at the headers my bank sent out and still can't figure out what the problem is.

I must support firefox but having it work on other browsers is good too.

The headers I put out are (which I confirmed by looking at my what my browser thinks the response is)

```
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: No-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

In html I start with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>The Title</title>
    <link href="/my.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
</head>
```

When I submit my form and hit back I can still see the page. I want to the browser to say document expired/invalid or have all the html reset so the form doesn't have user data still there. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [History.js by Benjamin Lupton](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/). You can register an event handler to the `onstatechange` event and then prevent the default action. We use the jQuery adapter and handle our own history records because of Ajax requests with a method like this.

```
History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {
    var HistoryState = History.getState();
    if (HistoryState) {

        var stateData = HistoryState.data;

        if (stateData) {


        }
    }
});
```

You should be able to use [e.preventdefault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017755) and stop the user going back.

We add the state data object for each page in the data object with `History.pushState(state, null, '');` but not sure if you need any data to stop them going back.

Comment: I know I didn't say this but the solution must work when javascript is disabled. Which is why i'm trying to figure out the expire/invalid document root.