# jquery mobile form submit resets form when trying to prevent submission

Tags: android, jquery, forms, cordova, jquery-mobile

so I have a form and if certain fields are empty of invalid, it doesn't submit the form, and it spits out an `alert()` telling them to fix it. The problem I am facing is that it resets the form and all the data the user has added disappears. Since my form is too big, I'll just show you my jQuery function:

```
$('#microForm').live('submit', function(){
                if ($('#barcode').val() != '') {
                    insertForm();
                } else {
                    alert('Insert Barcode');
                    return false;
                }
});
```

`<form id="microForm">`

I am trying this on an android app, with phonegap - inserting a form to a local database table (i.e sqlite).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't use jQuery mobile for a while so I'm not sure: can the problem be that "return false" force the page to reload? Can you try to remove it? (just an idea)

Comment: @Ciack404 using either `e.preventDefault` and `return false` still makes the page reload

Comment: @axrwkr yeah I've tried them all

Comment: You should use JQM popup or simpleDialog instead of alert. I don't know if that will fix the problem but that's the right way to show messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small adjustment to @Gajotres jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/bGdM6/1/

Instead of using the submit on the form you can check the submit button click/tap event and then submit the form if all values you need are there

JS:

```
$('#submit-btn').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($('#barcode').val() != '') {
        alert('Submit');
        $('#microForm').submit(); // <-- submit the form
    } else {
        alert('Insert Barcode');
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3>
            First Page
        </h3>
        <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <form id="microForm">
            <input type="text" value="" id="barcode"/>
            <input type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sweet that worked! is there a difference between `e.preventDefault` and `return false`?

Comment: @SNpn http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017755/whats-the-difference-between-e-preventdefault-and-return-false

Comment: Sorry to dig this back up, but when you remove the 'submit' event, you won't be able to submit the form by pressing the 'go' button an a smartphone. Is there an alternative for this?

Answer (score 1):

This should work, take a look at an example I made for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/bGdM6/

You should use **on** instead of **live**:

```
$('#microForm').on('submit', function(event){
    if ($('#barcode').val() != '') {
        alert('Submit');
    } else {         
        alert('Insert Barcode');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Change between **live** and **on** to see how it works.