# Perform redirect without bubbling click event

Tags: jquery, html, events, event-bubbling, jquery-click-event

I have an anchor element inside a div. I'm listening to both elements click event. When the user clicks the 'a' element, I need to prevent the click event bubble. But I need to keep the anchor working: the user has to be redirected to 'href' page:

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <a id="myLink" href="www.website.com">Click me</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#myLink").click(function() {
    // DO SOME STUFF

    return false;   // To prevent bubble
});

// This event handler has to be called only when the user clicked inside the div, but outside the link
$("#myDiv").click(function() {
    // DO SOME STUFF
});
```

The problem is that the user is not beeing redirected to "www.website.com". How can accomplish this?

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` for prevent bubbling.. not return false. returning false will prevent it from redirection.(prevents default action)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not preventing the event bubbling properly.

```
$("#myLink").click(function(e) {


    e.stopPropagation(); // this will prevent bubbling.
});

// This event handler has to be called only when the user clicked inside the div, but outside the link
$("#myDiv").click(function() {
    // DO SOME STUFF
});
```

You can read more about event.stopPropagation() here: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

If you want to redirect, you have to use:

```
window.navigate('url-goes-here');
```

Comment: Hmm, after some research, I got it.
I'll leave a link that may help other people: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017755/whats-the-difference-between-e-preventdefault-and-return-false