# prevent map area click to reload the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagemap

http://jsbin.com/iTeNiJIt/1/edit?output

I have a few map areas in my page. On clicking of any of these areas, i wish to create some animation within the same page. The problem is that the page is refreshed every time i click the area. Even after using the `stopPropagation()` method, i am unable to keep it that way. I just need to invoke some methods if the area of an image is clicked. Is there some better way ??

Comment: change the href's to href="javascript:;"

The reason it is refreshing is because having a # takes the user to the top of the current page and leaving it blank refreshes the page.

adding javasript:; to the href tricks it into thinking it needs to run some javascript so no more refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.stopPropagation` and `return false;` aren't the same thing. Return false on the click handler and you're all set.

```
$('map[name=blueBall] area').on('click',function(e){
    //... snip ...
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Good stuff:
[What's the difference between e.preventDefault(); and return false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017755/whats-the-difference-between-e-preventdefault-and-return-false)
[What's the difference between event.stopPropagation and event.preventDefault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault)

Comment: Don't have IE handy but adding `return false` works fine for me in Firefox. Something else change?

Comment: I think event propagation issue is resolved. But i am having problem with the 'event' thing. Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554197/using-the-event-parameter-inside-jquery-on-does-not-work-in-firefox-and-ie-bu 
Maybe you could help