# Javascript/Typescript - Prevent form from resetting on submit

Tags: javascript, forms, typescript, form-submit, onsubmit

I have a simple typescript class and a want to show the input results on submit. Even though this question is already asked, `event.preventDefault()` is not working. Maybe you can give me some hints?

```
class LoginPanel {

    public appDiv: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('app');

    constructor() {
        this.setForm();
        let btn = document.getElementById('loginButton');
        btn.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {event.preventDefault(); this.submitForm()});
    }

    public setForm(): void {
        this.appDiv.innerHTML = `<form id="loginForm" class="form-signin mt-5">
      <div class="text-center">
      <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
      </div>
      <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="">
      <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control mt-1" placeholder="Password" required="">
      <button id="loginButton" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>
    `;
    }

    public submitForm(): void {
        const elementFirst: HTMLElement = document.createElement('pre');
        const elementSecond: HTMLElement = document.createElement('pre');

        elementFirst.innerHTML = 'email: ' + document.getElementById('loginForm')[0].value;
        document.getElementById('loginForm').appendChild(elementFirst);

        elementSecond.innerHTML = 'password: ' + document.getElementById('loginForm')[1].value;
        document.getElementById('loginForm').appendChild(elementSecond);
    }

}

new LoginPanel();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you submit a form, you submit all its values, not just one button.

Accordingly, the right place to prevent the default is within the form element itself, not its buttons.

```
constructor() {
    this.setForm();
    const form = document.getElementById('loginForm');
    form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {event.preventDefault(); this.submitForm()});
}
```

You can see that would work [in this CodePen](https://codepen.io/WebReflection/pen/GXOrmY?editors=0010).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `onsubmit="return false"` on the form instead:

```
<form id="loginForm" class="form-signin mt-5" onsubmit="return false">
  <div class="text-center">
  <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
  </div>
  <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
  <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="">
  <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control mt-1" placeholder="Password" required="">
  <button id="loginButton" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

[**What's the difference?**](https://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/)

> The difference is that return false; takes things a bit further in that it also prevents that event from propagating (or "bubbling up") the DOM. The you-may-not-know-this bit is that whenever an event happens on an element, that event is triggered on every single parent element as well.

Alternatively, you could use [`event.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on the form element:

```
constructor() {
  this.setForm();
  let btn = document.getElementById('loginButton');
  btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => { this.submitForm()});
  let form = document.getElementById('loginForm');
  form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => { event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation; });
}
```

See: [What's the difference between e.preventDefault(); and return false?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2017755/5037430)